# .setModal() method on a JDialog

Tags: java, focus, jdialog

I want to make i so that the parent window cannot be accessed whilst the child window is active. I'm using the .setModal() method of the JDialog class, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
   if (clickEvent.getSource().equals(addCheckout1)){

        SupermarketCheckoutGUI checkout1 = new SupermarketCheckoutGUI();
        checkout1.setVisible(true);
        checkout1.setSize(670, 400);

        checkout1.setModal(false);
    }
```

Just to check, I've tried both true and false, but there is no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal(boolean)):

> Note: changing modality of the visible dialog may have no effect until it is hidden and then shown again.

Try calling `setModal(true)` before `setVisible`.

But `setModal` is deprecated, you should call `setModalityType` instead (the type you need is likely `APPLICATION_MODAL`), check this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
GP = new JDialog(f,"Game Over",Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
```